# Minimize picture size

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a picture into JavaFX application which is loaded +30 times into chart. I use this code to load it and shrink the size.

```
ImageView livePerformIcon = new ImageView(MainApp.class.getResource("/images/Untitledwdwd.png").toExternalForm());

            livePerformIcon.setFitHeight(100);
            livePerformIcon.setFitWidth(100);

            label.setGraphic(livePerformIcon);
```

Can you tell em how I can optimize this code for performance and memory is there a way to save resources during work.

Maybe livePerformIcon.setCache(true); can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Load the Image once and use the same Image instance for all the ImageViews. The example in the [ImageView javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) does this.